# Sign out iCloud - can't keep a copy of data. Download never ends

Tags: icloud

I have a small iCloud account of 5Gb and because i chosen to sync desktop and some other locations, now pending list of files to sync is very long and I just want to keep all data in mac and get rid of iCloud account. So I:

System Preferences / iCloud / Sign Out / Keep a copy

but downloading never ends and notification tells "iCloud drive needs to finish updating before continue with sign out" . I have been waiting for a whole day and it still never ends. Tried to relaunch few times - same, never ends. Also tried to move some folders, that I need, to other location (other that iCloud sync) and then sign out without downloading data, but it still throws same notification - "iCloud drive needs to finish updating before continue with sign out".

I ran EthreCheck and it points a major issue about huge list of pending files to be transfered to iCloud. Mac machine sometimes is a bit slow and ventilator is very noisy.

I was really stupid to use those free 5Gb from iCloud. I will never use it again (sorry for saying that, but it's a very big dissapointment, I paid A LOT for this computer and never expected to have such issues, when I dont buy something I get punished...)

Can anyone help to solve this?

High Sierra 10.13.4
Internet speed is ok

Answer (score 1):

You should resolve the pending transfers issue first. Move files to non-synced areas of your computer until the size of your iCloud Drive-synced folders is small enough the sync completes. Once it has completed, then you can disable it.